# Nuxt.config.js noscript innerHtml rendering as it on browser

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, innerhtml, noscript

[I have disabled javascript from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGNUi.png)

[Added inner html for noscript tag in nuxt.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCyPY.png)

[Expected behavior is it should add iframe element inside body but its rendering text as it. How can we add it as an element?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECmn0.png)

Answer (score 5):

Vue sanitizes HTML entities in every property. You need to use [__dangerouslyDisableSanitizersByTagID](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#dangerouslydisablesanitizersbytagid) or [__dangerouslyDisableSanitizers](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#dangerouslydisablesanitizers)

When you add it should work.

```
__dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['noscript']
```